# Getting an ASP button, created in code-behind, to not post back

Tags: c#, asp.net, code-behind

I have the following chunk of code in the code-behind that dynamically creates a table with an Edit button in the last cell of each row:

```
        Table table = null;

        string BranchName = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            TableRow tr;
            if (BranchName != dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString())
            {
                BranchName = dt.Rows[i]["Category"].ToString();
                // setup pane
                pane = new AccordionPane();
                // add pane to accordion
                acrDynamic.Panes.Add(pane);

                // pane content
                lbTitle = new Label();
                pane.ID = "Pane_" + BranchName;
                lbTitle.Text = BranchName;
                pane.HeaderContainer.Controls.Add(lbTitle);

                // pane container will have the table
                table = new Table();
                table.CssClass = "hoverTable";
                pane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(table);

                // top row
                tr = new TableRow();
                // cells
                TableHeaderCell th = new TableHeaderCell();
                th.CssClass = "hoverHeader";
                th.Width = 440;
                th.Text = "Provision";
                // set other properties
                tr.Controls.Add(th);
                // create next control
                th = new TableHeaderCell();
                th.CssClass = "hoverHeader";
                th.Width = 120;
                th.Text = "Mark for Review";
                // set other properties
                tr.Controls.Add(th);
                // etc for other columns
                table.Controls.Add(tr);
                // create next control
                th = new TableHeaderCell();
                th.CssClass = "hoverHeader";
                th.Width = 120;
                th.Text = "Issue Type";
                // set other properties
                tr.Controls.Add(th);
                // etc for other columns
                table.Controls.Add(tr);
                // create next control
                th = new TableHeaderCell();
                th.CssClass = "hoverHeader";
                th.Width = 120;
                th.Text = "Resolution";
                // set other properties
                tr.Controls.Add(th);
                // etc for other columns
                table.Controls.Add(tr);
                // create next control
                th = new TableHeaderCell();
                th.CssClass = "hoverHeader";
                th.Width = 120;
                th.Text = "Feedback";
                // set other properties
                tr.Controls.Add(th);
                // etc for other columns
                table.Controls.Add(tr);

            }

            tr = new TableRow();
            TableCell tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Provision"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["MarkForReview"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["IssueType"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Resolution"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            tc = new TableCell();
            tc.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Feedback"].ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);
            // add the button
            tc = new TableCell();
            Button button = new Button();
            button.Text = "Edit";
            button.ToolTip = Convert.ToString(i);
            button.ID = dt.Rows[i]["TemplateID"].ToString() + "-" + dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString();
            button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;
            button.OnClientClick = "return false;";
            button.Click += new EventHandler(btnEdit_OnClick);
            tc.Controls.Add(button);
            tr.Controls.Add(tc);

            table.Controls.Add(tr);
        }

MyContent.Controls.Add(acrDynamic);
```

All of this is used inside a holder, which explains that last line of code.

Over on the ASP side, I have the holder, plus a modalpopupextender that will pop up a modal form when the Edit button is clicked:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MyUpdatePanel" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:panel ID="MyContent" runat="server">

    <!--  ************************************  -->
                    <ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender id="MdlCommentsExtender" runat="server"     
                        targetcontrolid="MyContent" popupcontrolid="pnlComments" 
                        popupdraghandlecontrolid="PopupHeader" drag="True" 
                        backgroundcssclass="ModalPopupBG" Enabled="False"  >
                    </ajaxtoolkit:modalpopupextender>

                    <asp:panel id="pnlComments" style="display: none" runat="server" BackColor="White" CssClass="modalPopup">
                        <div class="HellowWorldPopup">
                            <div class="PopupHeader" id="Div3" style="border: thin solid #000000; vertical-align: middle; text-align: center; background-color: #C0C0C0; color: #000000; font-weight: bold; height: 40px; width:499px;" ><br />Pend Comment</div>
                                <div class="PopupBody" style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
                                    <table style="width: 490px">

                                        <tr style="text-align:left">
                                            <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblBenCat" runat="server" Text="Benefit Category:"></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblBenProv" runat="server" Text="Benefit Provision:"></asp:Label></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr style="text-align:left">
                                            <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblBenCatX" runat="server" Text="Benefit Category:"></asp:Label></td>
                                            <td style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblBenProvX" runat="server" Text="Benefit Provision:"></asp:Label></td>
                                        </tr>

                                        <tr style="text-align:left">
                                            <td colspan="2" style="padding:4px"><asp:Label ID="lblCommentBox" runat="server" Text="Feedback:"></asp:Label></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="2" style="padding:4px">
                                           <!--     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox_Old" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" TextMode="multiline" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small"></asp:TextBox>  -->
                                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentBox" TextMode="MultiLine" CssClass="textbox" Wrap="True" Height="70px" Width="270px" Font-Size="Small" Rows="3" runat="server"  onkeyup="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" onkeydown="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" onpaste="textCounter(this, this.form.remLen, 50);" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>  
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input readonly="readonly" type="text" id="remLen" name="remLen" size="2" style="width:280px; " maxlength="3" value="50" /> characters left
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div class="Controls" id="DivControls" runat="server">
                                    <table style="width: 450px; align-items:center">
                                        <tr>
                                           <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"> <asp:Button ID="mdlCmntsOk_Clicks" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CssClass="textbox" Height="28px" Width="75px" OnClick="mdlCommentsOk_Click" /></td>
                                           <td style="vertical-align: middle; text-align: center"> <asp:Button ID="mdlCmntsSave_Clicks" runat="server" Text="Save" CssClass="textbox" Height="28px" Width="75px" OnClick="mdlCommentsSave_Click" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>  
                    </asp:panel>
            </asp:panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

    <!--  ************************************  -->

</asp:Content>
```

So here's what's happening; if I comment out the `button.OnClientClick = "return false;";` line, the Edit button pops up the modal form and everything looks great, but neither the Save nor Cancel button responds at all.  Presumably because it does a postback.

In an effort to stop the postback, I put in the said `button.OnClientClick` line.  But now the Edit button does nothing.

Is there a way to get the Edit button to pop up that modal form and NOT post back?  It's inside an Update panel, I expected it to work as normal but I assume the fact that I'm adding controls via the code-behind (it must be done dynamically because the number can change based on a user's selection) I'm missing something.

Comment: try this one .. `btnEdit.UseSubmitBehavior = true`..

Comment: No change.  I did try that before I posted this question.  You're talking about changing "false" to "true" in the line 'button.UseSubmitBehavior = false;', right?